# How to map over a long tuple of instances of the same class?

Tags: list, class, haskell, tuples

Assume that we have a class C in Haskell that has a function f that returns a result of type R.
If we are given a long tuple t of instances of the class C, then how can we nicely obtain a list (or at least a tuple) of results of f on the members of t?

Note that the tuple is long, so solutions that include typing something per each member of the tuple are not perfect. We don't want to type that much.

```
-- GIVEN --

data R = R  -- more constructors here

class C a where
  f :: a -> R

data A = A
instance C A where
  f _ = R  -- some fancy f here

data B = B
instance C B where
  f _ = R  -- some fancy f here

-- some other instances of C here

t = (A, B, B, A, B, A, B) -- a long tuple of instances of C


-- QUESTION: How to obtain l as below, but in the nicest way? --

l :: [R]
l = let (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7) = t
    in [f t1, f t2, f t3, f t4, f t5, f t6, f t7]
```

Comment: Why do you have such a tuple in the first place? Tuples of size >3 are usually a sign that you've used them for something that should have better been done with e.g. records, or perhaps _nested 2-tuples_.

Comment: It was not my decision. Can we map over the fields of a record easier than over the coordinates in a tuple?

Comment: Not intrinsically, but you could perhaps make the record polymorphic in a way that naturally supports the type-changing map operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty standard use case for generic programming. It's such a common use case that there are libraries to not have to write the generic implementation.

### [one-liner](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/one-liner)

```
import Generics.OneLiner

l :: [R]
l = gfoldMap (For :: For C) (pure . f) t :: [R]
```

`gfoldMap` is a fold on the fields of a datatype, assuming they are all instances of a given typeclass allowing one to generically collect results, here this is `C`.

```
gfoldMap (For :: For C) :: (forall a. C a => a -> [R]) -> (A, B, B, A, B, A, B) -> [R]
```

Be careful this requires instances of `Generic`, derived by the base package only up to 7-tuples.
You can define your own tuples for which you derive `Generic`.

For various reasons, you may want to preserve the structure of your datatype rather than collecting results in a list. At the time of writing, `one-liner` is still a bit rigid in that respect, because it doesn't handle "type-changing traversals" (from `(A, B, B, A, B, A, B)` to `(R, R, R, R, R, R, R)`).

---

### [product-profunctors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/product-profunctors)

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Data.Profunctor
import Data.Profunctor.Product
import Data.Profunctor.Product.Default
```

We define a newtype to not pollute the environment with orphans.

```
newtype P a b = P { unP :: a -> b } deriving
  (Profunctor, ProductProfunctor)
```

We declare `f` as a `Default` way of mapping `A` and `B` to `R`.

```
instance Default P A R where def = P f
instance Default P B R where def = P f
```

The library implicitly extends this to tuples, mapping any tuple of `A` and `B` to a corresponding tuple of `R`.

```
-- Type signature required
t'_ :: (R, R, R, R, R, R, R)
t'_ = unP def t
```

You probably don't want to type the type signature. It can not be inferred because of type class shenanigans. However, it can be computed from the type of the input. You can thus define a type family (a type-level function) which replaces occurences of `A` and `B` with `R` in a tuple type. Actually, any type that looks like some `F a b c d e f` where `F` is a type constructor will be converted to `F R R R R R R`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

type family Rify (a :: k) where
  Rify (f a) = Rify f a
  Rify a = a
```

Specialize `def` (which has a type-inference-unfriendly type) to use this family:

```
defP :: Default P a (Rify a) => P a (Rify a)
defP = def

-- Type signature now optional
t' :: (R, R, R, R, R, R, R)
t' = unP defP t
```

---

### product-profunctors, bis

You can also get a list by picking the right profunctor.

As its name implies, product-profunctors works with `ProductProfunctor` in a general way. This profunctor collects `R` values in a list. It's a profunctor equivalent of `Const [R]` in `Control.Applicative`.

```
newtype Q a b = Q { unQ :: a -> [R] }

instance Profunctor Q where dimap f _ (Q q) = Q (q . f)

instance ProductProfunctor Q where
  purePP _ = Q (const [])
  Q x **** Q y = Q (\a -> x a ++ y a)

  -- Older versions of product-profunctor use these two instead.
  empty = Q (const [])
  Q x ***! Q y = Q (\(a, b) -> x a ++ y b)

-- or
--
-- newtype Q a b = Q (Star (Const [R]) a b)
--   deriving (Profunctor, ProductProfunctor)
--
-- unQ :: Q a b -> a -> [R]
```

Define default actions.

```
instance Default Q A b where def = Q (pure . f)
instance Default Q B b where def = Q (pure . f)
```

And again, these are implicitly composed to "traverse" tuples.

```
-- The second parameter doesn't actually matter, but
-- the type-checker doesn't know it so we put something for it
-- to infer. Could be `Q a ()`, anything that's not ambiguous.
defQ :: Default Q a a => Q a a
defQ = def

t'' :: [R]
t'' = unQ defQ t
```

This is actually very similar to how `one-liner` works internally, though it uses its own flavour of `ProductProfunctor` at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something along the line of

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DefaultSignatures #-}

class MultiC cs where
  type MultiR cs :: *
  type MultiR cs = R
  multif :: cs -> MultiR cs
  default multif :: cs -> R
  multif = f

instance MultiC A
instance MultiC B
-- ...

instance (MultiC x, MultiC y) => MultiC (x,y) where
  type MultiR (x,y) = (MultiR x, MultiR y)
  multif (x,y) = (multif x, multif y)
```

Then you can do

```
t :: ((A, (B, B)), ((A, B), (A, B)))
t = ((A, (B, B)), ((A, B), (A, B)))

l :: ((R, (R, R)), ((R, R), (R, R)))
l = multif t
```

You could in principle also extend this to have (pseudocode)

```
instance (MultiC α, MultiC β, MultiC γ ... MultiC ω)
             => MultiC (α,β,γ ... ω) where
  type MultiC (α,β,γ ... ω) = (MultiR α, MultiR β ... MultiR ω)
  multif (α,β,γ...ω) = (multif α, multif β, multif γ ... multif ω)
```

But as I commented, big flat tuples aren't really a good idea since Haskell has no proper way to abstract over them.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the methods listed in Li-yao Xia's answer, here's a solution using [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop):

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# language FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language DataKinds #-}
{-# language TypeApplications #-} -- for the Proxy

import Generics.SOP

tTol :: (Generic r, All2 C (Code r)) => r -> [R]
tTol = hcollapse . hcliftA (Proxy @C) (\(I a) -> K (f a)) . from
```

This solution will work with tuples, records, and sum types, as long as the type has a `Generics.SOP.Generic` instance, and all the fields have a `C` instance.